# Adding multiple items to special page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, categories, product

I have a quick how to question with Magento.

On my main site I need to have 7 links to special "categories" of items, but these don;t reflect categories of items. It is for a clothes shop so link may be to a summer wear page to only display items tagged as summer wear but from all types of item and categories.

What would the best way to go about creating this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that when you say 'taged' you mean the product has a attribute set to 'summer'. In that case:

If you have products that you want to group together by attribute and list similar to a category page without being in a category, you could try using the Fishpig Splash Page extension:
http://fishpig.co.uk/attribute-splash-pages.html
This extensions allows product attributes to group products instead of categories.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create categories for each of the 7 pages you mention, but hide them from the navigation in the category settings page.

you can then add your products to these categories as you see fit.

They will still be in their original categories too, but you can now link to the new pages and see them there too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to me, you would just create the categories like normal. Because products can belong to many categories, you would just assign on a per-product basis which ones need to be in your categories.